# How do I break a combined shape into separate pieces?

Tags: shapes, sketch-app

So I am trying to create a ring/donut chart in Sketch 3 and I created two circles, a large and a small one and subtracted the small circle from the large circle to get a ring shape. Then I went around and subtracted pieces from the circle with rectangle shapes to get something like this: 
[image]

When I roll my mouse over the shape I can see the outlines of each individual section of the circle. 
[image]If I want to be able to change the color of each individual piece, is there a way to split the shape into (in my case) 6 different shapes?

Answer (score 8):

so, here are a few steps that should make for a smooth sailing:

- create necessary shapes (circle at the bottom, several rectangles starting from the circle center (or lines that you will later need to expand to rectangles again), then a circle for the donut hole
- select all shapes and use "substract". This should bring us to your screenshots.
- select the combined shape and "flatten" the shape. This will break the initial shapes you had to separate slices. You still won't be able to recolor them separately
- select all slices in the layer palette and drag them out of their group
- now you can select each one separately and apply colors and styling.

[image: Creating donut charts in Sketch]

Comment: Sorry but the method suggested by @Spasimir Dinev is not working anymore with the latest (53.2) version of Sketch :( I know that this is not an answer but I can't comment, and since this is the top result in Google, i think that arriving in this page is misleading.